# accessing div in jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to access curr-dish and sub-dish class using jquery of third dish-wrapper div class...
how to access it since all three divs have same class
i want to access only third div...
i dont want to add any ids to the div..
providing my code below

```
<span class="status">
      <div class="dish-wrapper">
        <ul class="dishations">
          <li class="curr-li">
            <div class="curr-div">
              <a class="curr-dish sub-dish" "></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="dish-ul">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dish-wrapper">
        <ul class="dishations">
          <li class="curr-li">
            <div class="curr-div">
              <a class="curr-dish sub-dish" "></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="dish-ul">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dish-wrapper">
        <ul class="dishations">
          <li class="curr-li">
            <div class="curr-div">
              <a class="curr-dish sub-dish" "></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="dish-ul">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</span>
```

Comment: What selector are you using that is not working

Comment: i am trying to get the class but i am not able to access specifically

Comment: $('.sub-dish:eq(2)'); ?

Comment: i thought of using nth child but dont know how to find it

Comment: @lharby: thanks for your reply.....instead of giving no 3...can we access last one without number...because sometimes only two divs will be found

Comment: If it is always the last one you want, there is a last() jquery funciton. $('.sub-dish').last();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get element at particular location the and combine classes using dot `.`

```
$('.dish-wrapper:eq(2)').find(' curr-dish.sub-dish');
```

To access the last element you can use [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) or [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('.dish-wrapper:last').find(' curr-dish.sub-dish');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.....instead of giving no 3...can we access last one without number...because sometimes only two divs will be found

Comment: To access the last element you can use :last or .last()

Answer (score 2):

you can

```
$('.dish-wrapper:eq(2) .curr-dish.sub-dish')
```

Comment: instead of giving no 2...can we access last one without number...because sometimes only two divs will be found

Comment: @user2565289 yes `$('.dish-wrapper:last .curr-dish.sub-dish')`, you can use [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector

Answer (score 0):

Using :eq() is best way to access the third element like what others said. To access the curr-div and curr-dish sub-dish seperately, use can use the following:

```
$('.dish-wrapper:eq(2)').find('.curr-div');
$('.dish-wrapper:eq(2)').find('.sub-dish');
```

or collectively:

```
$('.dish-wrapper:eq(2)').find('.sub-dish,.curr-div');
```

NOTE: Please specify the class name without spaces so that it helps to access it in jquery/javascript. Ex. Here "curr-dish sub-dish" class name is not allowing to search for the class name precisely, able to check only the last part of the class name.

Good Luck!